# Event Delegation - cant change button class and value

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

I'm trying to ban users and remove their bans using vanilla javascript. I'm using datatables, so I have to use event delegation to fire events..

But when I done with banning user, I can't change button class or value, how can I do that ?

```
document.querySelector(".m-portlet__body").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.className === "btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block") {
            console.log(e.target)
            let id = e.target.dataset.id,
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                token = document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content;
            xhr.open("POST", "users/ban/" + id);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if (xhr.status === 200 && response.status === 'OK') {
                        e.target.className.replace("btn-danger","btn-success");
                        e.target.value = "Remove Ban"
                //I also try with;
                //e.target.classList.remove("btn-danger");
                //e.target.classList.add("btn-success");
                    } else {
                        console.log('failed');
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }

        if (e.target.className === "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"){

        }
    })
```

Comment: try using e.currentTarget instead of e.target

Comment: @ChrisLi it returns null,

Comment: do you get the correct target inside onreadystatechange?

Comment: @ChrisLi target is filtered with if statement, how can it change then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS strings are immutable, which means String#replace isn't going to replace the original string but return a new string.

```
 e.target.className = e.target.className.replace("btn-danger","btn-success")
```

Will change e.target.className value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

if the target is a button element and not `input[type=button]` then you can't change its text content with e.target.value, you need to use e.target.textContent = "New value";

Comment: so e.target returns string, not object itself ?

Comment: e.target returns an HTMLElement, not a string. className is a property of e.target.